# Replaceall() function working weird

Tags: replaceall

I have a requirement where I need to format 'Phone Number' field which is of type 'Phone'. It should not allow some of the special characters like %$#@*&, so am trying to replace each character individually with blank as below but it's acting weird.
Am using the expression as below to replace everything except alphanumeric values and the 2 characters ( & ).

```
Acc.Phone = Acc.Phone.replaceAll('[^\\(\\)][^a-zA-Z0-9]','');
```

And when I entered

> 7876*78(67)87564#7

Its formatted as

> 7877687567

Ex2:

> 96*85/56+98(45)874*568(

formatted as

> 985948756

If someone understand what's happening and where am doing the mistake, please correct me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using *two* character sets (a set starts with `[` and ends with `]`).

In your first example, the first match happens in the **bold** area:

> 787**6***78(67)87564#7

Because **6** matches `[^\\(\\)]` (it is not a parentheses), and ***** matches `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` (it is not a letter or number).

The next match occurs here:

> 7876*7**8(**67)87564#7

Because **8** matches `[^\\(\\)]`, and **(** matches `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`.

You can see that by trying to match two sets, you're actually matching a more complex pattern than you meant to.

Instead, you want *one* character set, and you can use `+` to indicate one or more occurrences (better performance):

```
Acc.Phone = Acc.Phone.replaceAll('[^\\(\\)a-zA-Z0-9]+','');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i got the concept now. But, to match every special character, do we need to prefix with \\? for example, replaceAll('[^\\*\\&a-zA-Z0-9]+',''); is not working as expected.

Comment: @Amulya Actually, no, you don't need to escape special characters like (, ), *, |, and so on *within a character set* (but, of course, [ and ] should be escaped). Also note that you need to use \\ to represent a single escape, and \\\\ to represent an actual backslash character. This is because the parser/compiler converts \\ into a literal \.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Hi Please try this regular expression to remove special character from   phone field 
    e.g :

    String strName = 'aZ^96*85/56+9^8(45)874*56^8(';
    String replacement = '[*/+()^a-zA-Z]';
    String result = strName.replaceALL(replacement,'');
    System.debug('Result ::'+result);

    Result will be : 9685569845874568
```

Comment: Hi Sagar, No this expression doesn't work. According to [*/+()^a-zA-Z], it should not replace alphabets right, but in your results, no alphabets at all.